# Active Admin bogged down with relationship; how to customize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, relationship

I've got a Product class that has_many Events -- in most cases there can be thousands of saved events -- and I've no need to display these on the ActiveAdmin Product page but ActiveAdmin is trying to load them anyway, which makes the app crash.

How can I best have the Product admin page ignore the relationship?  Something to do with customizing the collection?  Putting an empty scope on the Event model and calling that as default on the admin page?  Really unsure how to fix this.

Comment: `has_many :events, dependent: :nullify` can you try that. Am not also sure if it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here to either remove the filter from the index or scope the filter to a subset of options:

[ActiveAdmin automatically loading full association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552496/activeadmin-automatically-loading-full-association-table/18646968#18646968)